# show comment data on post laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, controller, eloquent

So yesterday I success to count comment from post, now I want to show comment in admin dashboard, so here is my code in controller

```
public function getComment()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $posts = $user->posts();

    foreach ($posts as $key => $value) {
        $posts[$key]->post_comments = PostComment::where('post_id', $value->id)->get(); 
    }
    return $posts;
}
```

and here is my web.php route code to get this comment

```
Route::get('/comment/post/{id}', 'DashboardController@getComment');
```

But it retrieve all comment even in different post, I only want to get comment from same post that I want. The weird one is when I click the button it retrieve random id not the id from the post, it look like this

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/comment/post/%7Bid%7D

hope you guys can help me thanks

Comment: Do you want to retrieve all the comments of a certain post, isn't ?.

Comment: yes correct bro

Comment: https://github.com/sapna-bhayal/post_comment here you will find complete solution

Comment: @AyamGeprek check my answer `https://stackoverflow.com/a/52418428/2876362`

Answer (score 2):

In **Laravel** we can use relationship to get related data. Here is the example to get user post comments:-

```
public function getComment()
{
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    $posts = Post::where('user_id', $userId)->with("post_comments")->get();
    return $posts;
}
```

In **Post** model you need to add this

```
use App\Comment;

public function post_comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

I hope this will help you to solve your problem with an easy way.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code to retrieve all the comments of certain post by post->id

```
public function getComment($id) {
    $comments = Comment::query()->where('post_id', $id)->get();
    return $comments;
}
```

Make sure the Comment model class have table name

Comment: still dont get it sorry

Answer (score 0):

I edited my code and got this solutions, I add id on the get comment parameter

```
    public function getComment($id)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $posts = $user->posts();

    foreach ($posts as $key => $value) {
        $posts[$key]->post_comments = PostComment::where('post_id', $id)->get(); 
    }
    return $posts;
}
```

Comment: check my answer. this is not the correct way to get post comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getComment($id) {
    $results = Post::with(['comments'])->where('post_id',$id);
    $posts = $results->get();
}
```

**Post.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model {

    public function comments() {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'post_id');
    }

}
```